# How do I (dynamically) link against math.h functions on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, llvm, math.h

I'm working on a C++ app which uses the LLVM JIT backend to compile code on the fly. In this JIT-compiled code, I want to be able to call all of the `math.h` functions, but currently it only works for some of them, i.e. `fabs` is present but `fabsf` is not.

It seems like the symbol for `fabs` is in the `msvsrt.lib` runtime library, but not `fabsf`, even though they're both declared in my system's `math.h`.  Am I linking to the wrong runtime library?  Or do I need to get an 'extended' math dll from elsewhere and link to that as well?

- Platform: Windows 7, Visual Studio Express 2012
- In properties, `C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime library` = Multi-threaded DLL (`/MD`)

Comment: Tip: Use dependencywalker to find out what functions are in what library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in some cases, math.h defines fabsf like this (taken from math.h included with MSVC2010 express)

```
#define fabsf(x)    ((float)fabs((double)(x)))
```

Your runtime library probably is implemented this way, meaning that fabsf does not exist at all, and "normal" fabsf is replaced by the C-preprocessor by a call to _fabs().